# on key up get selected drop down value not get correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have tried to get the selected dropdown value based on some other input type text field using below code. However every time it gets the first value, i.e `15`,
even when I have selected another `option`.

```js
$(".director_code").keyup(function() { //this is Dropbox class selector
  var schoolid = $("#schoolId").children(":selected").val();
  
  // i also tried:
  // $('#schoolId').find('option:selected').val();

  console.log(schoolid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="schoolId" id="schoolId" class="form-control  schoolId" required="">
  <option value="15">a</option>
  <option value="16">b</option>
  <option value="17">c</option>
  <option value="18">d</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="director_code" id="director_code" class="form-control director_code" pattern="[0-9]+" required="">
```

in snippet work perfectly but in my project not working well
show img
[image]

here i select second option i.e b but its display alert 15
but actual value of b is 16

Comment: So if I type `a` then you should get 15? b equal 16?

Comment: I put your code in a snippet where it works absolutely fine. Given the behaviour I would assume that the problem is because you have multiple elements with the same `schoolId` id, which is invalid. Use classes instead.

Comment: Also I'm not sure I understand the logic about why you use `type="text"` and `pattern="[0-9]+"`

Comment: var selectedVal = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

Comment: also try using class selector but same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine and as expected. On keyup event on input field, it is returning the selected option value.
What are you expecting then?
In the below screenshot, see the console log output w.r.t. input keyup logged with time.

[image: See this screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question maybe you want like this please check and let me know if something missed.

```js
$(".director_code").keyup(function() { 
  try
  {
     var value = $(this).val();
  //$("#schoolId").val($(this).val()); 
  var oschoolId = $('#schoolId > option').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).text()) == $.trim(value) }).val();
  
  if(oschoolId!=undefined)
  {
     $('#schoolId').val(oschoolId);
      console.log(oschoolId);
      console.log($(this).val());
  }
  }catch(e)
  {
     console.log("Error: "+e.message);
  }
});
$("#schoolId").change(function(){
    var value= $(this).children("option:selected").text();
    $('#director_code').val(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="schoolId" id="schoolId" class="form-control  schoolId" required="">
  <option value="15">a</option>
  <option value="16">b</option>
  <option value="17">c</option>
  <option value="18">d</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="director_code" id="director_code" class="form-control director_code" pattern="[0-9]+" required="">
```

Comment: Yes, but what you want?

Comment: i want selected dropdown value on texybox kuyup method

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```js
 $("#schoolId").change(function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        $('#director_code').val(selectedVal)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="schoolId" id="schoolId" class="form-control  schoolId" required="">
  <option value="15">a</option>
  <option value="16">b</option>
  <option value="17">c</option>
  <option value="18">d</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="director_code" id="director_code" class="form-control director_code" pattern="[0-9]+" required="">
```